# Capybara — как создать автоматически новый объект с помощью FactoryGirl после создания объекта user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Необходимо, чтобы в тесте после создания юзера также создавался объект Freelancer c user.id.

На данный момент есть следующий код:

**factories/user.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "user#{n}@test.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    password 'qwerty'
    password_confirmation 'qwerty'
  end

end
```

Необходимо также создать объект freelancer c freelancer.id = user.id

Как мне в factorygirl это реализовать, чтобы в тесте использовать

```
given(:user) { create(:user) }
  given(:freelancer) {create(:freelancer) }
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [метод `association`](https://github.com/brennovich/cheat-ruby-sheets/blob/master/factory_girl.md#associations):
Например так:

```
factory :user do
  # ...
  trait :freelancer do
    association :freelancer
  end
end
```

Но нужно быть осторожным - чтобы не получилось, например, циклических фабрик.

[Можно определять коллбэки](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl).
Например так:

```
factory :user do
  # ...
  trait :freelancer do
    after(:create) do |user|
      create(:freelancer, user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

Но оба варианта достаточно сложно контролировать.

Comment: cпасибо, а что такое trait в данном контексте?

Comment: @StefanHansch, [трейты](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits) это механизм, позволяющий более гибко группировать и сочетать свойства фабрик. Для моего примера `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` - создаст пользователя без привязанного к нему фрилансера. `FactoryGirl.create(:user, :freelancer)` - c. Подробности по ссылке выше.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант, это часто удобнее делать наследованием, а не толкованием:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :user do
      sequence( :email ) { |n| "user#{n}@test.com" }
      password 'qwerty'
      password_confirmation 'qwerty'
   end

   factory :freelancer, parent: :user do
      freelancer true
   end
end
```

и вызов:

```
given(:freelancer) { create(:freelancer) }
```